# How do I get camera position and rotation in A-Frame?

Tags: javascript, aframe, webvr

I can create an entity as camera:

```
<a-entity id="camera" camera look-controls wasd-controls></a-entity>
```

and get the position and rotation information, but in VR mode the built-in, default camera automatically takes over. 
How do I get the same kind of information about that default camera?
Or maybe I need a different KIND of information?
I tried this:

```
var scenic = document.querySelector('a-scene');
var cam = scenic.camera;
console.log("camera position x= " + cam.position.x);
```

But no matter when I trigger the cosole.log (ie; after moving about in the scene) it still signals:

```
camera position x= 0
```

For context: I want to make a projectile launcher that follows the camera around and allows users to launch from camera position in the direction and angle of the camera's FOV...
See example (triggered, at the moment, by pressing the P key in the registered component "launcher")

https://glitch.com/edit/#!/query-aframe-camera-position-rotation?path=index.html:27:0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var position = document.querySelector('a-scene').camera.el.object3D.position;
```

Comment: This worked very well, Diego, until I entered VR mode on a mobile device.
Query is here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57451862/in-a-frame-how-do-i-get-the-vr-camera